# Access Control from Ribbon ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I am new to WPF and have started to use the Ribbon control in VS2010.

```
 public class RibbonAddCustomer : ICommand
  {
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        AddCustomer addCustomer = new AddCustomer();
        addCustomer.ShowDialog();
        Customer myCustomer = addCustomer.customerDetails;
        addCustomer.Close();

        // MainWindow.Customers.Add(myCustomer);

    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

I have created a WPF RibbonWindow and added a Ribbon to the form.  I attached an event handler which displays the CustomerDetails form.  Now I would like to add the customer entered to a ComboBox on the main form.  The event fires, and the customer entry from displays. I cannot figure out how to access the control on the form from the RibbonAddCustomer event to update the ComboBox on the main form.

I have tried passing in a parameter to the RibbonAddCustomer event, but this is always null.

```
 <r:RibbonButton Command = "{StaticResource mycmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Label="Add Customer" />
```

Any suggestions?  Kind of lost.  -Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Window property in your RibbonControl so that you have a reference to your main window.

```
public MainWindow MyMainWindow {get;set;}
```

When your application starts up, set the MyMainWindow property to your main window.